# How to make a list with Unique entries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list

I want to make an MVC C# List with unique values in it. Here is the scenario. My List is like this:

List A

```
ItemNo       FileName 

001      =>   A.txt
001      =>   B.txt
002      =>   A.txt
002      =>   B.txt
003      =>   A.txt
```

I want to make it a new List like,

List B

```
ItemNo       FileName 

001      =>   A.txt, B.txt
002      =>   A.txt, B.txt
003      =>   A.txt
```

Is there any way that I can make it workable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ with [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx), assume you have class:

```
class Item
{
    public string ItemNo { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

var result = list.GroupBy(item => item.ItemNo)
                 .Select(g => new Item
                   {
                       ItemNo = g.Key,
                       FileName = string.Join(", ",  g.Select(s => s.FileName))
                   });
```

Comment: It doesn't return the exact results of the question but is a better solution than what I proposed :)

Comment: Repeated file name cannot be entered in a FileName column. Is there any way can i restrict filename repetition. Now the result is something like this, A.txt,B.txt,A.txt. I need to make it like, A.txt, B.txt.

Comment: @Deva: you can continue to use g.Select(s => s.FileName)).Distinct()

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

**Method**

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var fileAssistant in duplicateList)
{
    if (result.ContainsKey(fileAssistant.ItemNo))
    {
        result[fileAssistant.ItemNo] = string.Format("{0}, {1}", result[fileAssistant.ItemNo], fileAssistant.FileName);
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(fileAssistant.ItemNo, fileAssistant.FileName);
    }
}
```

**Setup**

```
var duplicateList = new List<FileAssistant>(new[]
                                        {
                                            new FileAssistant("001", "A.txt"), 
                                            new FileAssistant("001", "B.txt"), 
                                            new FileAssistant("002", "A.txt"), 
                                            new FileAssistant("002", "B.txt"),
                                            new FileAssistant("003", "A.txt")
                                        });
```

**File Assistant class**

```
public class FileAssistant
{
    public FileAssistant() { }
    public FileAssistant(string itemNo, string fileName)
    {
        ItemNo = itemNo;
        FileName = fileName;
    }

    public string ItemNo { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```